# PhpMyadmin : Webserver Installation using apache

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I was installing PHPMyAdmin and when the option came to choose the web server I did not press the spacebar button n now I don't know how to get back to it. Please give me a solution. Thank You

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but if there's a problem installing PhpMyAdmin it may be better to remove the installation and reinstall. In my experience it's faster to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can reconfigure phpmyadmin by typing the following command in the terminal :-

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Then choose Apache2 when it asks for configuring Web Server ! Remember to hit "Space" button after selecting Apache2 as web server !

Another helpful link you can see is given below :-
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04